# Перемещение блоков с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html

Как восстановить порядок блоков через `js`? Пробовал и `appendChild` и `insertBefore`. Как-то всё криво. Или не туда или разваливается.

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 2</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 5</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 3</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 4</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вопрос для гадалок и ясновидящих?

Comment: а что не так написал?

Comment: Наверное, нужно было так написать: отсортировать блоки с классом `b` по содержимому дочернего заголовка `H2`?

Comment: @РустамГимранов но прежде написать свой код и сказать, что именно там не получилось

Answer (score 2):

```js
const divSort = () => {
  let item = document.querySelectorAll('h2'),
    count = 1;
  newDiv = document.createElement('div');

  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {

      if (+item[j].textContent.slice(-1) == count) {
        newDiv.appendChild(item[j].parentNode);
        count++;
      }

    }
  }

  document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector('.a'));
  newDiv.classList.add('a');
  document.body.appendChild(newDiv)
}

divSort();
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 2</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content2</li>
      <li>Content2</li>
      <li>Content2</li>
      <li>Content2</li>
      <li>Content2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content1</li>
      <li>Content1</li>
      <li>Content1</li>
      <li>Content1</li>
      <li>Content1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 5</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content5</li>
      <li>Content5</li>
      <li>Content5</li>
      <li>Content5</li>
      <li>Content5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 3</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content3</li>
      <li>Content3</li>
      <li>Content3</li>
      <li>Content3</li>
      <li>Content3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 4</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content4</li>
      <li>Content4</li>
      <li>Content4</li>
      <li>Content4</li>
      <li>Content4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если честно, долго ломал голову. Не думаю, что моё решение рациональное, но, по крайней мере, оно работает :)

Comment: О, спасибо. Близко. Я не указал, что в li контент тоже разный и надо весь блок перемещать, а не только h2))

Comment: @Константин, перемещается же весь блок. parentNode стоит

Answer (score 2):

```js
const resortTagDivs = (containerClass, sortingDivClass) => {
  let sortedDivsObj =  {};
  let items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.' + sortingDivClass)]; 
  items.forEach((el) => {
    let elementNumber = parseInt(el.querySelector('h2').textContent.match(/\d+/)[0]);
    sortedDivsObj[elementNumber] = el;
  });

  document.querySelector('.' + containerClass).innerHTML = '';
  for (let values of Object.values(sortedDivsObj)) {
    document.querySelector('.' + containerClass).append(values);
  }  
}

resortTagDivs('a', 'b');
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 2</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content2</li>
      <li>Content2</li>
      <li>Content2</li>
      <li>Content2</li>
      <li>Content2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content1</li>
      <li>Content1</li>
      <li>Content1</li>
      <li>Content1</li>
      <li>Content1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 5</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content5</li>
      <li>Content5</li>
      <li>Content5</li>
      <li>Content5</li>
      <li>Content5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 3</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content3</li>
      <li>Content3</li>
      <li>Content3</li>
      <li>Content3</li>
      <li>Content3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 4</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content4</li>
      <li>Content4</li>
      <li>Content4</li>
      <li>Content4</li>
      <li>Content4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
}

.b:nth-child(1) {
  order: 2;
}

.b:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}

.b:nth-child(3) {
  order: 5;
}

.b:nth-child(4) {
  order: 3;
}

.b:nth-child(5) {
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 2</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 5</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 3</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h2>Item 4</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: js, а не css...

Comment: Если нет принципиальной разницы, то что можно сделать на css, лучше делать на css...